# Are names of characters copyrighted?

Tags: copyright

I am **not** developing a game or creating game characters. What I am trying to do is give a name to the software that I am creating in my spare time. It seems there is a game character by the same name (I am not a gamer but a google search to check the name revealed it). The software is intended to be free but might make money in the future, so I want to know this.

**Are names of characters in games copyrighted and is it illegal to use them to name other unrelated software components and applications that might or might not  make money?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [law.se], as we're not a legal advice site.

Comment: If its off topic then I wonder why the tag exists, but I think if an admin moves this to law instead of closing, it would be very helpful.

Comment: A tag existing doesn't mean that the subject defined in the tag is on-topic (almost anybody can create tags); see [this related discussion](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/how-can-we-improve-the-tutorial-tag-definition). There are specific kinds of copyright-related questions that may be considered on-topic here (or may have been historically), but this one is not particularly game development related at it's core. The IP law that covers names is generally [trademark, not copyright](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8774/are-invented-names-protected-by-copyright).

Comment: Fair enough. I'll post it in law myself.